# Help me prove this relation

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

This should be easy, but I feel like I'm missing something.
I work for this exam, and I don't understand why:

$\forall x,y\in(2,+\infty):$

$$(x-2)^{\ln(y-2)/3}=e^{\ln(x-2)\ln(y-2)/3}.$$

Comment: $a^b=e^{b \ln (a)}.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I urge you to take a look at my edit to for reference on how to get your equations showing right for next time :) (Though I don't know what \{3} was supposed to mean...)

Comment: thanks, it meant the interval without 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is your question :$$(−2)^{(1/3((−2)))}=^{(1/3(−2)(−2))}$$
$a=e^{ln(a)}$ or $x-2=e^{ln(x-2)}$

Comment: yup, thanks, idk why i missed that